# How to create an empty environment with custom caption?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, captions, environments

This code shows a simple centered table that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \chapter{One}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{My first table.}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcr}
            One  & Two  & Three\\
            Four & Five & Six
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would now like to define a new environment called `appendix` where the caption should look like this:

> **Appendix 1:** My first appendix.

It should also be possible to make a `\listofappendices` which I can locate right beneath my `\listoftables`.

I already tried to modify this code but it did not yield the result I want:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listexamplename{List of Appendices}
\newcommand\listofexamples{%
    \section*{\listexamplename}\@starttoc{exs}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{example}
\newenvironment{example}[2][]{\refstepcounter{example}%
    \ifx\\#1\\ % if #1 is empty
    \addcontentsline{exs}{subsection}{\theexample~#2}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{exs}{subsection}{\theexample~#1}%
    \fi
    \begin{list}{}{% options
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}%     leftmargin
            \parsep\parskip%                  space between paragraphs within an item
            \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%   space between items
        }
        \item {\centering\textbf{Appendix \theexample:} ~#2}
        \item}{\end{list}}
```

Please note that I would like to write something like this and produce the same output as shown before but with a caption that does not look like this:

> **Table 1:** My first table.

But like this:

> **Appendix 1:** My first appendix.

That is, I would like to write something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \listofappendices
    \chapter{One}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{My first table.}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcr}
            One  & Two  & Three\\
            Four & Five & Six
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{appendix}[ht]
        \caption{My first appendix.}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcr}
            One  & Two  & Three\\
            Four & Five & Six
        \end{tabular}
    \end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to call a table ‘appendix’???

Comment: I want an environment that is called `appendix` but it should be able to contain a table, a figure, just text or whatsoever. The table in the `appendix` environment here is just an example. But adding another `appendix` with a figure should then be called “**Appendix 2**: My second appendix.”.

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simple to start a real appendix, and use sections inside this appendix ( redefining their numbering)?

Comment: What do you mean by that? A new chapter called “Appendix” that contains several sections? Usually, I would do that. But my project partners want it to be that way.

Comment: You can define new floating environments with `float` (which cooperates with `caption`), but I wouldn't call this environment ‘appendix’, as it might interfere with real appendices, even if there would be no problem displaying `appendix` in  the caption.

Comment: It is not clear whether or not the new appendix environment must be a float, and what is the meaning or purpose of the two arguments. What would be the meaning of a float that could be srpead across several pages as implicitly suggested by your last comment ? Why typeset your content including caption as a list ? In brief what are the precise requisites for your custom environment ?

Comment: @Jhor This is just code I copied from somewhere because I have no clue on how to create such new environments. I actually thought that it should be quite simple to create it but all I saw were these cryptic bits of code where I don’t know what all the details mean.

Comment: Ok but  can you answer my questions ?

Comment: You can also use the newfloat package, which has fewer nasty side effects than float.

Comment: @Jhor (1): I have no idea what `float` means and how to deal with it. I just copied this code. (2): Again: I just copied the code and have no idea what it actually does. (3): I want it to be like the `table` or `figure` environment where I can put in everything that I like. Just the caption should be different and I would like to have a `\listofappendices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environments are implemented as macros, for example `\figure` and `\endfigure`.  Alas, the macro `\appendix` is already used, so one would need to modify the newfloat (or float) packages to use `\renewenvironment` instead of `\newenvironment`.

However, that only applies to the environment name.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=app,listname={List of Appendices},
  name=Appendix,placement=htp,within=none]{app}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \listofapps
    \chapter{One}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{My first table.}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcr}
            One  & Two  & Three\\
            Four & Five & Six
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{app}[ht]
        \caption{My first appendix.}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcr}
            One  & Two  & Three\\
            Four & Five & Six
        \end{tabular}
    \end{app}
\end{document}
```