# Redefine Figure (or Table) as "Supplementary Materials Figure (or Table)"

Tags: environments, texlive, renewcommand

I am preparing some Suppementary Materials for a manuscript, and they say that I need my Figures in the Supplement to be called "Supplementary Materials Figure 1" (say). Now, I know how to change the Figure numbering (to Figure S1), etc by doing the following:

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{S\arabic{figure}}\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand\thetable{S\arabic{table}}\setcounter{table}{0}
```

However, here I have to change the "Figure" itself to be called "Supplementary Materials Figure". Is this possible to do in LaTex?

Comment: Have you tried using `\renewcommand{figurename}{Supplementary Materials Figure}` and the same with `tablename` ?

Comment: You can also use the newfloat or float packages to create new float types with their own names, counters, and `\listof...`s.  That way you can still use normal figures and tables.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnKormylo can you please detail further your suggestion?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538933/two-captions-for-algorithm-in-algorithm2e-package/539219?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C36.4880#539219 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499772/how-to-create-an-empty-environment-with-custom-caption/499786?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C29.8823#499786